# Apache correctly redirects all URLs of webpage to HTTPS except for base URL http://dev.example.com

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

Setup is on an ecommerce platform. eCommerce platform uses a `uri.php?` URI management system to handle serving page contents. Only able to see the htaccess file for the site for the time being [limited server privileges]. No htaccess files in any parent directories that could be impacting my current htaccess file.

The htaccess file is set up as follows:

```
> force www and https rewriterules
> direct to uri.php
```

But here's the problem, when I try to visit dev.example.com and look at the 301s I get, it looks like this:

```
301 redirect to: http://dev.example.com/store/uri.php?
301 redirect to: https://www.dev.example.com/store/uri.php?
```

which *seems* like it's hitting the htaccess rules out of order, but not entirely sure that's correct.

`https://dev.example.com` and `http://www.dev.example.com` do NOT have this issue! But I'm having a hard time understanding why...

Anyone have an idea what might be going on here? Something that I'm overlooking like a noob or something that will need access to httpd.conf to really understand what's happening?

Thanks for any and all help!

Here's the htaccess file in more detail:

```
RewriteEngine on

#force www and https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#redirect requests to uri manager
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/store/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /store/uri.php? [QSA,L]
```

and the server variable referenced above

```
HTTP_HOST = www.dev.example.com
```

Comment: There would seem to be "something else" going on, possibly in your server config. Any other `.htaccess` files? Your redirects are not optimal, since you would see two redirects when accessing HTTP and non-www. However, you say the first redirect seen is to HTTP - the `.htaccess` code you've posted would not do this. "`301 redirect to: http://dev.example.com/store/uri.php?`" - Do you actually see the trailing `?` on the redirected URL? (You should not.)

Comment: Do you have a DirectoryIndex document in the document root?

Comment: @MrWhite no, no ? at the end of the HTTP response/location URL
Also, no DirectoryIndex declared (and no file such as index.php or index.html) - perhaps that's the reason?

Comment: I added a DirectoryIndex /store/uri.php at the top of my htaccess file, and it fixed the problem completely. Thank you so much @MrWhite!!

Comment: If you want to add your answer, I'll make sure to mark it as correct. Thanks again :)